# Spring Boot Actuator 'http.server.requests' metric MAX time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I have a Spring Boot application and I am using Spring Boot Actuator and Micrometer in order to track metrics about my application. I am specifically concerned about the 'http.server.requests' metric and the MAX statistic:

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.079653001
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.032696019
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "200", 
                "400"

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I suppose the MAX statistic is the maximum time of execution of a request (since I have made two requests, it's the the time of the longer processing of one of them).

Whenever I filter the metric by any tag, like `localhost:9090/actuator/metrics?tag=status:200`

```
{
        "name": "http.server.requests",
        "measurements": [
            {
                "statistic": "COUNT",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
                "value": 0.029653001
            },
            {
                "statistic": "MAX",
                "value": 0.0
            }
        ],
        "availableTags": [
            {
                "tag": "exception",
                "values": [
                    "None"
                ]
            },
            {
                "tag": "method",
                "values": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am always getting 0.0 as a max time. What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 3):

- **What does MAX represent** **([MAX Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247185/spring-boot-actuator-max-property))**

MAX represents the maximum time taken to execute endpoint.

Analysis for `/user/asset/getAllAssets`

```
COUNT  TOTAL_TIME  MAX
5      115         17
6      122         17  (Execution Time = 122 - 115 = 17)
7      131         17  (Execution Time = 131 - 122 = 17)
8      187         56  (Execution Time = 187 - 131 = 56)  
9      204         56  From Now MAX will be 56 (Execution Time = 204 - 187 = 17)
```

---

- **Will MAX be 0 if we have less number of request (or 1 request) to the particular endpoint?**

No number of request for particular endPoint does not affect the MAX *(see an image from Spring Boot Admin)*

---

- **When MAX will be 0**

There is *[Timer](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Timer.java)* which set the value 0. When the endpoint is not being called or executed for sometime Timer sets MAX to 0. Here *approximate timer value is 2 to 2.30 minutes (120 to 150 seconds)*

*[DistributionStatisticConfig](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/DistributionStatisticConfig.java)* has `.expiry(Duration.ofMinutes(2))` which sets the some measutement to 0 if there is *no request has* been made for last *2 minutes (120 seconds)*

Methods such as `public TimeWindowMax(Clock clock,...)`, `private void rotate()` *[Clock](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Clock.java)* interface has been written for the same. You may see the implementation [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.2.x/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/TimeWindowMax.java#L117)

---

- **How I have determined the timer value?**

For that, I have taken 6 samples (executed the same endpoint for 6 times). For that, I have determined the *time difference between the time of calling the endpoint - time for when MAX set back to zero*

---

***MAX*** property belongs to  [*enum Statistic*](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.java) which is used by [*Measurement*](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Measurement.java)
*(In Measurement we get COUNT, TOTAL_TIME, MAX)*

> public static final Statistic [MAX](https://static.javadoc.io/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.6/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.html#MAX)
>
> The maximum amount recorded. When this represents a time, it is
>   reported in the monitoring system's base unit of time.

---

*Notes:* 
This is the cases from metric for a particular endpoint (here `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/user/asset/getAllAssets`).

For generalize metric of `actuator/metrics/http.server.requests`

MAX for some endPoint will be set backed to 0 due to a timer. In my view for MAX for `/http.server.requests` will be same as a particular endpoint.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

[The document](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/pull/101/files) has been updated for the MAX.

> NOTE: Max for basic `DistributionSummary` implementations such as
>   `CumulativeDistributionSummary`, `StepDistributionSummary` is a time
>   window max (`TimeWindowMax`). It means that its value is the maximum
>   value during a time window. If the time window ends, it'll be reset to
>   0 and a new time window starts again. Time window size will be the
>   step size of the meter registry unless expiry in
>   `DistributionStatisticConfig` is set to other value explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the individual metrics by using `?tag=url:{endpoint_tag}` as defined in the response of the root `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests` call. The details of the `measurements` values are;

- **COUNT:** Rate per second for calls.
- **TOTAL_TIME:** The sum of the times recorded. Reported in the monitoring system's base unit of time

> - **MAX:** The maximum amount recorded. When this represents a time, it is reported in the monitoring system's base unit of time.

As given [here](https://static.javadoc.io/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.6/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.html), also [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.java).

---

The discrepancies you are seeing is due to the presence of a timer. Meaning after some time currently defined `MAX` value for any tagged metric can be reset back to `0`. Can you add some new calls to your endpoint then immediately do a call to `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests` to see a non-zero `MAX` value for given tag?

This is due to the idea behind getting `MAX` metric for each smaller period. When you are seeing these metrics, you will be able to get an array of `MAX` values rather than a single value for a long period of time.

You can get to see this in action within Micrometer source code. There is a [`rotate()`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.2.x/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/TimeWindowMax.java#L117) method focused on resetting the `MAX` value to create above described behaviour.

You can see this is called for every [`poll()`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.2.x/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/TimeWindowMax.java#L89-L90) call, which is triggered every some period for metric gathering.