# SimpleMeterRegistry clears data if data not polled every minute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a simple spring boot app with the following config (the project is available [here](https://github.com/dome313/micrometer-elastic/tree/120-seconds-no-data) on GitHub):

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      simple:
        mode: step
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

The above config creates `SimpleMeterRegistry` and configures its metrics to be step-based, with 60 seconds step. I have one script that sends 50-100 requests per second to the service dummy endpoint and there's the other script that polls the data from `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests` every X seconds. When I run the latter *script every 60 seconds everything works as expected*, but when the script is run **every 120 seconds**, the response always contains **zeros** for `TOTAL_TIME` and `COUNT` metrics.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

I have read the documentation [here](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_client_side). The picture below
[image]
could indicate that a registry will try to aggregate the data for the previous interval only if pollAsRate is called during the current interval. This will explain why it does not work for 120 seconds interval. But this is just my assumption, does anyone know what is really happening here?

Spring boot version: **2.1.7.RELEASE**

**UPDATE**

I did a similar test with `management.metrics.export.simple.step=10s`, it works fine when polling interval is 10s and not working when it is 20s. For 15s interval it sporadically works. So, it's definitely related to the step size and polling frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what is happening.

On every request to `/actuator/metrics`, `MetricsEndpoint` is going to merge measures (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/MetricsEndpoint.java#L130)). That is done by collecting values for all meters with `measurement.getValue()`. The `StepMeasurement.getValue()` will not simply return the value, it will update the current and the previous intervals and counts, and roll the count (see [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/v1.1.5/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/step/StepMeasurement.java#L37) and [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/v1.1.5/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/step/StepDouble.java#L61)).

**StepMeasurement.getValue**

```
public double getValue() {
  double absoluteCount = (Double)this.f.get();
  double inc = Math.max(0.0D, absoluteCount - this.lastCount.sum());
  this.lastCount.add(inc);
  this.value.getCurrent().add(inc);
  return this.value.poll();
}
```

**StepDouble.poll**

```
public double poll() {
    rollCount(clock.wallTime());
    return previous;
}
```

How is this related to the polling interval? If you do not poll `/actuator/metrics` endpoint, the current and previous intervals will not be updated, thus resulting in the current interval not being up-to-date and metrics being recorded for the "wrong" interval.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX`, `TOTAL_TIME`, `COUNT` is the property of *[Statistic](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.java).*

*[DistributionStatisticConfig](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/DistributionStatisticConfig.java)* has `.expiry(Duration.ofMinutes(2))` which sets the some measutement to 0 if there is *no request has* been made for last *2 minutes (120 seconds)*

Methods such as `public TimeWindowMax(Clock clock,...)`, `private void rotate()` has been written for the same. You may see the implementation [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.2.x/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/TimeWindowMax.java#L117)

***[More Detailed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250893/10961238)***

Comment: "Sets the some measutement to 0 if there is no request has been made for last 2 minutes (120 seconds)", my script is sending a request every second, therefore the service always has data to calculate the metircs. It is just that when I'm polling the metrics every 2 minutes, no metrics are returned. Is this expiry related to metrics polling?

Comment: @MarkoVranjkovic yes IMO